# VBA CODE to open PPT on my office laptop return with run time error'-214741

Tags: vba, powerpoint

To open a PPT via VBA I am getting run-time error '-2147417856(800100100)':

System called failed

```
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application 
Dim PPT = New PowerPoint.Application 
PPT.Visible = True 
PPT.Presentations.Open (Path)
```

Comment: Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application Dim PPT = New PowerPoint.Application PPT.Visible = True  PPT.Presentations.Open (Path) End Sub

Comment: @kunwarwahi Please edit your question and paste your code there. code in comment are not formatted and thus is difficult to read.

Comment: Could there be any settings issue, as all other macros are working find.

Comment: @RaymondWu apologies, I am getting an error in re ink *your post appear......."

Comment: @kunwarwahi Not sure what could cause the error, I have tried to copy/paste your code from the comment to the question but it's incomplete. For one, you should use `Set` instead of `Dim` when assigning object to variable e.g. `Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application`.

Comment: @RaymondWu I have tried that as well but it doesn't work

Comment: @kunwarwahi Where are you running this code from? I tried running this from PowerPoint and Excel and both works. Which line did the error occured? What is `Path`?

Comment: @raymondWu - error occurs at Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application and path is ("H:\My Documents\Test\Test.pptx")

Comment: @kunwarwahi Are there more code? Have you tried running a sub consist of just these 4 lines (with `Path = "H:\My Documents\Test\Test.pptx"` of course) to see if it works?

Comment: @RaymondWu yes, Sub Macro1 ()

Comment: @RaymondWu could it be due to office laptop?

Comment: @kunwarwahi It could be, I can't say what's the exact issue though since the code works. Maybe reinstalling MS Office helps.

Comment: Are you sure powerpoint is installed? Can you run it manually?

Comment: @braX - Yes it's installed version2016

Comment: Have you set a reference to PowerPoint ( Tools | References )